# Strange SslStream buffering issue

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-2.0

I am using an `SslStream` to encrypt a TCP connection between a client and server.  The problem is that when the client reads the data, it may be given a bunch of zero bytes instead of the real data.  Here is an example that shows the issue:

```
        // Server
        using (NetworkStream tcpStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            Stream stream = tcpStream;
            if (ssl)
            {
                SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, true);
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, false, SslProtocols.Default, false);
                stream = sslStream;
            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[] {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02};
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            buf = new byte[] {0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03};
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }



        // Client
        using (NetworkStream tcpStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            Stream stream = tcpStream;
            if (ssl)
            {
                SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                    tcpStream, 
                    true, 
                    delegate { return true; }
                );
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(
                    "localhost",
                    null,
                    SslProtocols.Default,
                    false
                    );
                stream = sslStream;
            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[7];
            stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            // buf is 01010101010101 as expected

            buf = new byte[9];
            stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            // buf is 020000000000000000 instead of the expected 020303030303030303
            // a subsequent read of 8 bytes will get me 0303030303030303
            // if the ssl bool is set to false, then the expected data is received without the need for a third read
        }
```

It appears as though the client needs to read from the stream in the exact same number of bytes as the server wrote them only when an `SslStream` is being used.  This can't be right.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
buf = new byte[9];
stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

requests `stream` to read between 1 and 9 bytes into `buf`. It does not always read exactly 9 bytes.

The [Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) returns  the number of bytes actually read.

Try this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[9];
int offset = 0;
int count = buffer.Length;

do
{
    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break; // end of stream
    offset += bytesRead;
    count -= bytesRead;
}
while (count > 0);
```

Comment: Ahh, pretty amateur mistake.  I guess I was just blissfully ignorant since the TcpStream always gave me exactly what I wanted.  I suppose then that wherever I have code that reads from the stream I should be using the logic you've described here?  Seems like a pretty good candidate for a utility function whenever a stream read is done.